# Spring Sleuth | Create fresh new (detached/orphaned) Trace

Tags: spring, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I got a [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) application making use of [Spring Sleuth](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/) for tracing inter-service calls. Within that application a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) exists that performs http requests in a loop (pseudo-code below):

```
class HttpCaller implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    performHttpCall();
    // "loop"
    executor.submit(this::run);
  }
}

// start it once
scheduler.submit(new HttpCaller());
```

If I now have a look at the traces produced by Sleuth and stored in [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/) I can see that all http calls are associated to a single Trace. Most likely because the trace context is handed over during the call to `ScheduledExecutorService::submit`.

*How can I clear the current trace before starting the next iteration so that each http call will result in a new detached/orphaned trace?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Sleuth 2.0 you can call on the `Tracer` a method to create a new trace. In the older version of sleuth I guess what I'd do is to use an executor that is **NOT** a bean. That way you would lose the trace and it would get restarted at some point (by rest template or sth like that).

Comment: how can I start a new trace using the Tracer? I was not able to find such a method. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Same question here. Did you found it?

Comment: I guess they removed that method (I'm on Sleuth 3.1.0).

Comment: Theoretically, you can do a tracer.withSpan(null) which will null the current span and then you can create a new span and that should create a new trace